# AlarmManager SetExact() Is Not Triggering While App Is Not Running - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, alarmmanager

I'm creating an activity logging app, Where **it's user can explicitly set a series of time** first. On those set times I want to launch one of the activity which need to popup & collect data from user and go away.

*(Data like how much you drink today, How many km jogged, What foods you ate, Did you exercise today etc...).*

These are the constrains

- The app is very much dependent on precise user defined dates and times. So I think I
  had to use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() with AlarmManager
- User can be fully aware that the app need to run always. I've no issues running my tracker as a HIGH_PRIORITY Foreground service if that can offer reliable explicit data collection from user. In that case how to change this code?

For this purpose, I tried using AlarmManager. But it is triggering only when the app is in forground. How can I call the activity even if the app is not running on precise timings?

```
fun setAlarm()
{
    val myIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0)

    val alarmManager: AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5)

    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Or should I use start an always running foreground service and later on set times throwing an Intent to OS for starting an activity? Is it a good approach?

Comment: "On those set times I want to launch one of the activity which need to popup & collect data from user and go away" -- you cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android. Use a high-priority `Notification`.

Comment: I'm okay using HIGH_PRIORITY notification as the user is aware and trust app. In that case what change you suggest on this code?

Comment: "In that case what change you suggest on this code?" -- do not try using a service `PendingIntent` for an activity. `MainActivity` hopefully is an activity. `PendingIntent.getService()` will try to start `MainActivity` as a service. This will not work.

Comment: Yes I understood and modified the question. Now the activity is launching after 5secs but only during the app runs. When I start the app and close it, AlarmManager is not triggering the app again after 5secs. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: "Is there any workaround for it?" -- as I wrote originally, you cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android. Use a high-priority `Notification`.